# What does SQL Server 2008 error "The code page 0 is not supported by the server." mean?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm getting a SQL Server exception in my C# code with the following message:

> The code page 0 is not supported by the server.

I haven't found much searching for that error. What does this mean?

EDIT:

Just in case someone has the same issue, the method that was calling the SQL stored procedure set several parameters.  Each of those parameters had the following set

```
param.CompareInfo = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlCompareOptions.IgnoreCase
```

Removing that fixed the issue.

Comment: Is this a guessing game or can't you tell us __anything__ about the code that throws this??? Do you maybe to set a code page?

Comment: A code page is an ordered set of characters of a given script in which a numeric index, or code point value, is associated with each character. A Windows code page is typically referred to as a character set or charset. Code pages are used to provide support for the character sets and keyboard layouts that are used by different Windows system locales. From [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx#Code_Page_Defn)

Comment: @TaW I don't set a code page that I'm aware of, just running a stored procedure.  I didn't want to know how to fix the issue though, I just wanted an explanation of the meaning behind that error.

Comment: OK, so can you be sure that the SP is causing the problem? DBMS also use code pages and '0' is probably not a valid one. What DBMS do you use?

Comment: Probably somewhere you are doing `BULK INSERT ... WITH ( CODEPAGE = 0 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A code page is an ordered set of characters of a given script in which
>   a numeric index, or code point value, is associated with each
>   character. A Windows code page is typically referred to as a character
>   set or charset. Code pages are used to provide support for the
>   character sets and keyboard layouts that are used by different Windows
>   system locales.

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx#Code_Page_Defn)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Can you help me understand what the '0' is describing?

Comment: Provide the code you are using to access the database so I can take a better look. It looks like your code might be directing SQL to use code page 0 instead of the one that it is using.